# (Public) IP address [x.x.x.x] of Synology has been blocked by SSH

Tags: firewalls, ssh, router

For the past few months I regularly see alerts on my Synology about SSH connection being blocked. Somebody (here a nice Chinese guy from 222.186.15.158) was attempting to connect to my NAS with the root account (Fortunately PermitRootLogin is disabled).

What I am a bit worried because if I see a public address here, it means my NAS is somehow reachable from the internet. However all ports are closed on my front router, NAT is disabled, DMZ is disabled.

When I try to `nmap` my router from the outside I get this :

```
$ nmap -Pn -p- x.x.x.x

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-17 01:07 CEST
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x
Host is up (0.012s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
113/tcp  closed ident
2000/tcp open   cisco-sccp
5060/tcp open   sip

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.23 seconds
```

So there is no SSH entry point.

How would it be technically possible to see a public IPv4 address attempting to connect to my LAN NAS?

From the Synology DSM I exported the last log entries from the *Log Center*.

```
System
Level,Log,Date & Time,User,Event,
Warning,System,2020/05/16 21:34:44,SYSTEM,Host [222.186.15.158] was blocked via [SSH].
Warning,System,2020/05/04 07:46:14,SYSTEM,Host [222.186.30.59] was blocked via [SSH].
Warning,System,2020/04/15 06:46:01,SYSTEM,Host [51.91.158.54] was blocked via [SSH].
Warning,System,2020/04/13 17:46:00,SYSTEM,Host [27.78.14.83] was blocked via [SSH].
Warning,System,2020/04/13 17:45:55,SYSTEM,Host [116.105.216.179] was blocked via [SSH].
Warning,System,2020/04/12 17:46:52,SYSTEM,Host [86.36.20.20] was blocked via [SSH].
```

This log is an SQLITE database directly connected to `syslog-ng`.

My router is a Salt Fiber Box from my internet provider. The interface is very primitive. Even the *Expert* mode gives no transparency about the *Firewall features*. I don't even know what *Medium* means in this case:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Some thoughts

From [symcbean](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/543/symcbean) comment three scenarios are possible:

- Something is already inside my network.

  - Then I would probably see attacks from local addresses it is stupid to give me the information of what is the IP of my attacker.
- My router is compromised.

  - Unfortunately this options is conceivable
- There is an issue with the information I gave.

  - As I said, no NAT/DMZ options are enabled on my router (screenshots attached)
  - The Synology has no DDNS configured, no tunnels, no VPN

From [mti2935](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/69717/mti2935) comment

- The router could be compromised, the attacker could have punched a hole for himself only accessible from his own IP (or range of IPs).

  - In this case I would expect this attacker to do a more massive attack, not few attempts every few weeks.

Comment: You said, " *However all ports are closed on my front router, NAT is disabled, DMZ is disabled* ". If that were true, you would have not Internet connection at all.

Comment: Is SSH enabled on the Synology on port 22 or something else ?

Comment: Yes indeed ssh is enabled on my Synology and this is wanted

Comment: I am asking if SSH is enabled on port 22 or a non-standard port that you may have missed, because by default nmap only scans the 1000 most 'popular' ports. Add `-p 0-65535` or `-p-` for a full sweep.

Comment: @Anonymous Yeah I eventually did `-Pn -p-`. It took several hours, but I got the exact same result.

Comment: Can you post relevant log entries ? You could run `netstat` on the Synology to see if there is network activty you are not aware of.

Comment: @Anonymous Nothing to report with `netstat -tupln` ran on the NAS. I don't find the logs of the NAS from the filesystem. All I have is entries such as the title of my question in the System Logs application

Comment: Not familiar with this device but it should be Linux-like. Is there a `/var/log` directory and maybe an `auth.log` file in that directory ?

Comment: If all the information you have provided is accurate, and the default route on the NAS box is the router you describe above then either someone else is already inside your network (unlikely) or your router is compromised. However I suspect that that there may be an issue with some of the information you have presented here.

Comment: @symcbean if somebody is inside why do I see a public address. This seems absurd. It’s possible that the router is compromised. But then I would find an opening with nmap, and the attacker would do a more massive attack. I get these logs only few times each month

Comment: If the router has been compromised, then it's quite possible that the attacker punched a hole for himself that is only accessible from his own IP (or range of IPs).  That would explain why your nmap scans are not showing anything.  Also it could be possible that the attacker is in the early stages of a much larger attack.  If you google 222.186.15.158, you'll find other nefarious activity from this IP.  I agree with @Anonymous that connection activity logs from the NAS would be helpful at this point.

Comment: @nowox: I present three scenarios to explain the events you describe and you respond to the one I state is the most unlikely. You don't seem to be treating this very objectively.

Comment: @symcbean Sorry about this, I was hiking in the middle of mountains with poor network. I'll respond and update my question with more logs as soon as I get home.

Comment: @mti2935 What kind of connection activity logs are you looking for? I updated my question btw.

Comment: Is the NAS creating a port forward using UPnP?

Comment: The logs that you posted are what I was looking for.  These indeed seem to show connections from outside/remote ip's, as you said.  Moreover, if you google the remote all ip's, all of them are on various abuse lists for brute-force SSH attacks.  This could be bot-net activity.  The question is, how are they traversing your router.  Can you try using a few of the open port checking tools online (such as https://www.portcheckers.com/, https://canyouseeme.org/, etc) to test port 22 on your public ip, to see if you get a different result than you got with your nmap scans?

Comment: Have you tried to get into SSH on your synology from a different network than yours ?

Comment: @mti2935 I have tried many online tools such as the ones you mention. I have the same result than with `nmap`

Comment: This is a real head-scratcher.  It's a mystery as to how the attackers are seemingly able to traverse your router and make ssh connection attempts to the NAS on your inside LAN from their outside IP, while you are unable to repeat this despite all of your attempts from multiple IP's.  Notwithstanding, if I was in your shoes, I would no longer trust your ISP-provided router.  You might want to consider running the ISP-provided router in bridge mode, and using a separate hardware firewall (that you have more control over) directly behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might found the culprit, at least in my case, rsync.
I use rsync on my NAS and that port is open, has port redirection on my router and guess what it uses SSH, so that would explain why my NAS gives me those same SSH warnings eventhought SSH is turned off on my Synology.

Have had no more logs about bruteforce attempts on SSH sofar since I closed the port today.